# Find the maximum value in two dynamic ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula

*My original question was not quite as clear as it might have been, so here's a bit of clarification:*

What I'm working with is a list of items for use in a pivot table. Each row represents an item, and a person can have multiple items, so the same person's name appears on multiple lines. The items are ranked 1-15. For the final output we're looking for a count of individuals per item. We want each person to be counted exactly once, and we want them counted for the highest ranked item they have. In the end this gives us a tally of groups of individuals, the groups being the highest ranked item each person has.

People's names are in Column A and the ranks are in Column F. I had a formula that could find the highest F per A, but it failed when new data was loaded and the total number of rows changed.

*This was my original question, along with the formulas I was working with:*

I have an array formula that works unless the number of entries in the table changes. I know how to find the last row, but I don't know how to combine the two. Here are the details:

I have a table that's pulling data from a dynamically updating query on another sheet. It has duplicate text values in column A and unique numeric values in column F. In column G I have an array formula. If the F value on the current row is the maximum F for the corresponding A, it returns 1, if not it returns "No" (easier to filter and count only numbers elsewhere, don't ask).

```
A    ...     F
Joe         1.2
Joe        12.7
Ralph       3.5
Ralph       4.1
Ralph       0.5
Warren     12.9
Mike        6.4
Mike        8.5
Ralph       1.3
Warren      7.9
Warren     14.8
```

```
{=IF(A2="","",IF(F2=MAX(($A$2:$A$1719=A2)*($F$2:$F$1719)),N(1),"No"))}
```

This formula works fine except that the total range of entries can change on any given day. Today there are 1718 rows, plus column headers. Tomorrow I could have 1300 entries, or 2000 (though never more than 2000). If there are blank lines in column A, the entire formula fails and the rest of the report collapses.

I know I can get the number of the last row in column A with text by using:

```
=MATCH(TRUE, INDEX(ISBLANK('SourceQuery'!A1:A2001), 0, 0), 0)-1
```

Today that formula returns "1719" which is exactly what I want. In the first formula you can see two cell range references involving that row number.

What I can't figure out is how to combine the two. In theory I should just be able to replace the $A$2:$A$1719 reference in the first formula with some sort of reference involving the second formula, but I can't find a way to do this that works. Any ideas?

*For future lost souls trying to solve the same problem as me, there were two good answers to this. You can read the details in the answers below, but here's the quick reference.*

If you want to do this by my original method of using an array formula, use this:
`{=IF(A2="","",IF(F2=MAX((INDIRECT("$A$2:$A$" & (MATCH(TRUE, INDEX(ISBLANK('SourceQuery'!A1:A2001), 0, 0), 0)-1))=A2)*(INDIRECT("$F$2:$F$" & (MATCH(TRUE, INDEX(ISBLANK('SourceQuery'!A1:A2001), 0, 0), 0)-1)))),N(1),"No"))}`

If you don't want to be a crazy person like I was, you don't need to use an array formula at all.
`=IF(A2="","",IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,F:F,">"&F2)>0,"No",1))`

Comment: The subject line I used might be slightly misleading, but I couldn't think of a really accurate summation of the problem. What I want is to find the max of all F values that correspond to any given instance of a repeated A value, but the total range that has to be checked changes from day to day (and repetitions of A values aren't necessarily anywhere near each other in the list). Does that make more sense?

Comment: To clarify further, in case future people face a similar problem, what I'm working with is a list of items for use in a pivot table. Each row is an item, and a person can have multiple items, so the same person's name appears on multiple lines. The items are ranked 1-15, and we're looking for a count of individuals per item. We want each person to be counted only once, and we want them for the highest ranked item they have. Anyway I have two answers below that both work.

Comment: I don't mind adding clarification back to my question. Anything to help future people as confused as me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to find the `MAX` value here - you only need to know whether or not there are any higher values for that specific column A value. You can use `COUNTIFS` function for that, which is faster, doesn't require "array entry" and, crucially, can be applied to the whole column with no significant downside.

Based on that you can use this formula in `G2` copied down

`=IF(A2="","",IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,F:F,">"&F2)>0,"No",1))`

That should give you the same results without needing to worry about the size of the data

Comment: That's perfect. Way less clunky than the way I was coming at the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `INDIRECT` which takes in the cell address as a string.

So replace `$A$2:$A$1719` with

```
INDIRECT("$A$2:$A$" & (MATCH(TRUE, INDEX(ISBLANK('SourceQuery'!A1:A2001), 0, 0), 0)-1))
```

and replace `$F$2:$F$1719` with

```
INDIRECT("$F$2:$F$" & (MATCH(TRUE, INDEX(ISBLANK('SourceQuery'!A1:A2001), 0, 0), 0)-1))
```

the final output should look like:

```
{=IF(A2="","",IF(F2=MAX((INDIRECT("$A$2:$A$" & (MATCH(TRUE, INDEX(ISBLANK('SourceQuery'!A1:A2001), 0, 0), 0)-1))=A2)*(INDIRECT("$F$2:$F$" & (MATCH(TRUE, INDEX(ISBLANK('SourceQuery'!A1:A2001), 0, 0), 0)-1)))),N(1),"No"))}
```

Comment: Ah I thought I could do something with 'INDIRECT' but I couldn't figure out how to make it work. Now I see what I was doing wrong. Thanks.